# How can I run a Node.js socket project automatically on a web server?

Tags: html, node.js, sockets, npm, web

How to launch a Node.js socket project automatically on a web server?
I have to run my socket project in host in webserver and run automatically server.js .. help me please
server.js code :

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const http = require('http').createServer(app);
    const io = require('socket.io')(http);
    const mysql = require('mysql');

// Set up a MySQL connection
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        // host: 'localhost',
        // user: 'root',
        // password: '',
        // database: 'laravel'

        host: 'greatejsocket.mysql.db',
        user: 'greatejsocket',
        password: '*********',
        database: 'greatejsocket'
    });

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
    });

    http.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('listning on port 3000');
    });

// Connect to the MySQL database
    connection.connect();

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log('Client connected');
        dataUpdate(socket);
    });

    function dataUpdate(socket) {


// Fetch the users from the database and emit them to the client
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }
            let users_age = [];
            let users_locale = [];

            // for(i=0; i< results.length; i++){
            //     const date = new Date(results[i].naissance);
            //     const year = date.getFullYear();
            //     age = 2023 - year;
            //     users_age.push(age)
            // }
            // socket.emit('dataupdate', users_age);
            users_locale.push(results[1].latitude);
            users_locale.push(results[1].longitude);

            socket.emit('dataupdate', users_locale);
            console.log('users', users_age);

            socket.on('event-from-client', data => {
                console.log(data);
            });

        });

        // socket.emit('dataupdate', Array.from({length: 2}, ()=> Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)));

        setTimeout(() => {
            dataUpdate(socket);
        }, 3000)
    }
```

index.html code :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="server.js"></script>
<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

package.json code :

```
{
  "name": "socketserver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "require": "^2.4.20",
    "socket.io": "^4.6.1"
  }
```

When I launch our server, it shows:
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at server.js:3:19